# just a canvas in a tkinter window

Tags: python, layout, geometry, tkinter

If I try to place a canvas in a tkinter window and nothing else with this code:

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
class Application(Frame):
    def createWidgets(self):
        self.can = Canvas(self.master, width=500, height=250)
        self.can.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.can.create_line(0,0,500,200)
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()
root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

a window is never created. I found that adding a button to create a canvas works:

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
class Application(Frame):
    def makecanvas(self):
        self.grid_forget()
        self.can = Canvas(self.master, width=500, height=250)
        self.can.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.can.create_line(0,0,500,200)
    def createWidgets(self):
        self.inst = Button(self)
        self.inst["text"] = "GO!"
        self.inst["command"] =  self.makecanvas           
        self.inst.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=15, sticky=N)
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()
root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

Also, If I comment out the create canvas function, the button I removed with self.grid_forget() doesn't disappear. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing geometry managers in the same window. You can only use one within a given parent widget. You can use both within your application as a whole, but you are using them both on widgets that have the same parent.

You need to rewrite your code to use only grid, or only pack, for all widgets directly under the root window.

***Using the*** `grid` ***geometry manager***

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *


class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()      
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.can = Canvas(self.master, width=500, height=250)
        self.can.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.can.create_line(0,0,500,200)

root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

***Or using the*** `pack` ***geometry manager***

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *


class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.can = Canvas(self.master, width=500, height=250)
        self.can.pack()
        self.can.create_line(0,0,500,200)

root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

Comment: thanks, that worked, and "tkinter" is used in python 3.1, with themed widgets. http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/tkinter.ttk.html

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, Im still using Python 2.6. Ill remove that comment from my answer so as not to confuse others.

Comment: Just to be clear: you can't use both grid and pack in the same _parent_ but you can use both in the same app.